# Windows phone 8.1 get map corners geopoint

Tags: c#, algorithm, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps, geopoints

I trying to find the Geopoint of corners

- TopLeft
- TopRight
- BottomLeft
- BottomRight

The information that MapControl provides is

- Center (Geopoint)
- ZoomLevel (Double min:1, max:20)
- ActualHeight (Double)
- ActualWidth (Double)

Based on that information can I find  the corners?

I was thinking something like that:

```
double HalfHeight = Map.ActualHeight / 2;
double HalfWidth = Map.ActualWidth / 2;
```

So that means that `Center` Geopoint is located on `HalfWdidth` (X) and `HalfHeight` (Y). Can somehow this help me?

**Edit:** My problem was very similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24468236/3546760) question as [rbrundritt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245450/rbrundritt) mentioned but it was giving only TopLeft and BottomRight. Based on the accepted answer of that question (which is by rbrundritt) I also completed the other two and wrapped them in Extension, check my answer below. Thank you rbrundritt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get view bounds of a Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468236/get-view-bounds-of-a-map)

Comment: @rbrundritt thank you for providing that link, it helped me a lot and  yeah it's almost duplicate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static class MapExtensions
{
    private static Geopoint GetCorner(this MapControl Map, double x, double y, bool top)
    {
        Geopoint corner = null;

        try
        {
            Map.GetLocationFromOffset(new Point(x, y), out corner);
        }
        catch
        {
            Geopoint position = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
            {
                Latitude = top ? 85 : -85,
                Longitude = 0
            });

            Point point;
            Map.GetOffsetFromLocation(position, out point);
            Map.GetLocationFromOffset(new Point(0, point.Y), out corner);
        }

        return corner;
    }

    public static Geopoint GetTopLeftCorner(this MapControl Map)
    {
        return Map.GetCorner(0, 0, true);
    }

    public static Geopoint GetBottomLeftCorner(this MapControl Map)
    {
        return Map.GetCorner(0, Map.ActualHeight, false);
    }

    public static Geopoint GetTopRightCorner(this MapControl Map)
    {
        return Map.GetCorner(Map.ActualWidth, 0, true);
    }

    public static Geopoint GetBottomRightCorner(this MapControl Map)
    {
        return Map.GetCorner(Map.ActualWidth, Map.ActualHeight, false);
    }
}
```