# Bing Maps Bounding box for UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.locationrectangle(v=vs.105).aspx) MSDN page, there was a nice way of finding the coordinates of corners of the bounding box for Bing Maps until Windows 8. The function mentioned in the link is `LocationRectangle`.

We're developing a Universal application for Windows 10 and there seems to be no way to get the bounding box. Is there a library or plugin that enables us to do so? Or is there a function that we are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GetLocationFromOffset function. Using this for each corner of the view will give you the same result.

See [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.getlocationfromoffset)

Comment: How would I find the corners? Also, the documentation doesn't explain much; can you elaborate?

Comment: The offset is the offset from the center point of the map. For example you can get the top left coordinate by calling map.GetLocationFromOffset(new Point(-map.width / 2, -map.height / 2, out yourGeoPoint) and the bottomRight by calling map.GetLocationFromOffset(new Point(map.width / 2, map.height / 2, out yourGeoPoint).

Comment: Also see these questions and answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468236/get-view-bounds-of-a-map
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688496/get-distance-of-mapcontrol-border-in-degrees

Answer (score -1):

What is wrong with following? ( Area being a `GeoBoundingBox` )

```
area.NorthwestCorner.Latitude,
area.NorthwestCorner.Longitude,
area.SoutheastCorner.Latitude,
area.SoutheastCorner.Longitude
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geoboundingbox.northwestcorner.aspx

Or is that not enough?

Comment: How did you compute the `area` variable?

Comment: Thought you had that ;) but maybe this can help https://github.com/LocalJoost/WpWinNl/blob/uwp/uap10.0/WpWinNl.Maps/MapExtensions.cs

Comment: Wait, so is `GeoBoundingBox` a built in class? I think not.