# Get distance of MapControl border in degrees

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I have a MapControl and would like to know how many degrees are currently shown on the x and y axes.

First example:
[image: map landscape]

360 degrees are shown on the x axis (longitude)

~90 degrees are shown on the y axis (latitude)

(The zoom level is 3.2 and it's max zoomed out)

Second example:
[image: map portrait]

~220 degrees on the x axis (longitude)

180 degrees on the y axis (latitude)

(zoom level: 1.7; max zoomed out)

I tried calculating the current degrees on the x axis using following code:

```
double dist = 360 * Math.Pow(0.5, macSurrounding.ZoomLevel - 1);
```

but it doesn't work, because the zoom level is just strange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the MapControl's [GetLocationFromOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.getlocationfromoffset.aspx) method to calculate the geographic coordinates of the south-east and north-west corner points of the current map viewport. The width and height of the viewport would be the latitude and longitude differences of these points.

```
Geopoint northEast;
Geopoint southWest;

map.GetLocationFromOffset(new Point(map.ActualWidth, 0), out northEast);
map.GetLocationFromOffset(new Point(0, map.ActualHeight), out southWest);

var width = northEast.Position.Longitude - southWest.Position.Longitude;
var height = northEast.Position.Latitude - southWest.Position.Latitude;
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it:

Longitude:

```
360 * Math.Pow(0.5, mcMapControl.ZoomLevel - 1) * mcMapControl.ActualWidth / 409.5;
```

Latitude:

```
180 * Math.Pow(0.5, mcMapControl.ZoomLevel - 1) * mcMapControl.ActualHeight / 409.5;
```

Comment: This calculation is wrong, because it does not take the map projection into account (and of course uses the dubious magic value `409.5`). See my answer.

Comment: I got the magic value while experimenting with the map.

If i zoom out complete on a map with the size of 1000x1000 I can see 360deg longitude and 180deg latitude with a zoom level of about ~2.2

If i zoom out on a map with the size of 409.5x409.5 I also can see 360deg and 180deg with a zoom level of 1.

So i figured out, that the zoom only refers to the center of 409.5x409.5 ^^